# Conditional Ajax.Actionlink in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik ASP.NET  MVC 2.0 Grid on a partialview  . Here in this Grid there is column say " Status" having values as " active " & " inactive". I want to show a delete link in only those rows having Status Column Value as " Active ".

I am rendering this partialview on my main View having a ViewModel and my partialview is rendered using a descriptor .

I tried to use a ClientTemplate / Template but I am not able to put a condtional check before displaying a delete Link . How to achieve this using C# 4.0 ASP.NET4.0 code . I need some sample code . Its very urgent so your help is deeply appreciated .Thanks in advance for going through my problem

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will most likely need to wrap a conditional block inside the template definition which to determine whether the delete link should be output or not. Check the general templates definitions from the demos below and try this out to see how it goes:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/templatesclientside
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/templatesserverside

Comment: Thats not working for me ... i am using AJAXLink .. but i am binding my Grid with Server not Ajax .. so AjaxActionlink doesnt work